# Angular filter show found not found indicator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm bulding a datagrid based on AngularJS and i got stucked on filter function.

I need to build a filter that interacts with the json to tell me  if the value filtered was found or not found. The filter must be applied to generic jsons

I have the following json

```
var json = [{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Homer",
    "Role":"Analyst",
    "Found":"true"
},{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Maggie",
    "Role":"Manager",
    "Found":"true"
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "name":"Lisa",
    "Role":"CEO",
    "Found":"true"
},]
```

If i type "Li" or "Mana" on a search text box, Lisa and Maggie object must be shown because "Li" is part of Lisa's name and "Mana" is part of Manager role name and found key on Homer object must be set to false

Use ng-repeat with |filter is not an option, since I got lot of things going on like submenus on each row, colspans, etc

Thanks

Comment: so you want to filter on the view from an input but you cant use `|filter`?

Comment: I don't get why you can't use `filter`.

Comment: If you use AngularJs with large data you will take a performance hit if you over use ng-repeat. With "I got lot of things going..." I'm guessing he is already pushing the performance and does not want to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the filter in the controller using $filter avoiding the ng-repeat.

```
$filter('filter' )(Json, textToFilterBy);
```

Here is the Docs for $filter
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Here is an example of it working in a controller.

https://jsfiddle.net/Michael_Warner/khLhLou8/6/

Comment: he has a mistake in his json data and so do you. Remove the `,` at the end before the square brackets.